# goroutine or multithreading is not working in golang

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, goroutine

I was trying to implement multithreading in golang. I am able to implement go routines but it is not working as expected. below is the sample program which i have prepared,

```
func test(s string, fo *os.File) {
    var s1 [105]int
    count :=0
    for x :=1000; x<1101;x++ {
    s1[count] = x;
        count++
    }

    //fmt.Println(s1[0])
    for i := range s1 {
        runtime.Gosched() 
        sd := s + strconv.Itoa(i)
        var fileMutex sync.Mutex
        fileMutex.Lock()
        fmt.Fprintf(fo,sd)
        defer fileMutex.Unlock()
    }
}

func main() {
    fo,err :=os.Create("D:/Output.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        go test("bye",fo) 

    }



}
```

OUTPUT - good0bye0bye0bye0bye0good1bye1bye1bye1bye1good2bye2bye2bye2bye2.... etc.
the above program will create a file and write "Hello" and "bye" in the file.

My problem is i am trying to create 5 thread and wanted to process different values values with different thread. if you will see the above example it is printing "bye" 4 times.

i wanted output like below using 5 thread,

good0bye0good1bye1good2bye2....etc....

any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: You have nothing blocking your main function. Your program exits before you see all the output.

Comment: @JimB thanks for your reply. but it is writing in to the file and working.

Comment: Besides the lack of blocking in main (which you need to fix first), the mutex isn't locking _anything_ since they aren't shared between goroutines, plus there's a separate mutex initialized for each loop so it's not even blocking within the goroutine. You call defer to unlock the lock when you aren't returning. You should never need to to call `runtime.GoSched` in a well behaved program.

Comment: @JimB thanks again for your valuable comment. got your point. but can you please correct my program so that i can create 5 thread and each thread will print different values. it will be great help for me. i did it from my side but can not understand. please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to block in your main function until all other goroutines return. The mutexes in your program aren't blocking *anything*, and since they're re-initialized in each loop, they don't even block within their own goroutine. You can't defer an unlock if you're not returning from the function, you need to explicitly unlock in each iteration of the loop. You aren't using any of the values in your array (though you should use a slice instead), so we can drop that entirely. You also don't need `runtime.GoSched` in a well-behaved program, and it does nothing here.

An equivalent program that will run to completion would look like:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

var fileMutex sync.Mutex

func test(s string, fo *os.File) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 105; i++ {
        fileMutex.Lock()
        fmt.Fprintf(fo, "%s%d", s, i)
        fileMutex.Unlock()
    }
}

func main() {
    fo, err := os.Create("D:/output.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go test("bye", fo)

    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Finally though, there's no reason to try and write serial values to a single file from multiple goroutines, and it's less efficient to do so. If you want the values ordered over the entire file, you will need to use a single goroutine anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your cooperation .. i will try to implement it. I am hoping it is creating 5 thread and each thread is printing different values. By the way is this a right way to implement multithreading in GoLang or is there any other simple way by which we can do so?

Comment: Go doesn't expose OS threads, so yes, you use goroutines for concurrency.

Comment: got your point. But still i am not able to achieve parallelism here. in the above example i am locking and processing data one by one. I want to process all the threads parallel. any idea how can i do so? for example - if there are collections and wanted to fetch data from service or database how can i do that?

Comment: @user2768132: I don't know what you mean. Each goroutine is running concurrently, probably scheduled in parallel over multiple threads, the locking is solely around the shared file write. Querying a database is something completely unrelated.

Comment: thanks for your reply. acctually i am trying to HIT a service url just before writing to the file. after hitting the URL i am writing response in to the file.  If i am seeing the current example i am thinking that it is not running parallel due to lock. first it is locking and writing in to the file. till that time all the other threads are waiting. am i correct? Please guide me.

Comment: I mean to say it is creating multiple goroutins but when it is processing first it is locking one thread and hitting URL and writing the code. till that time other threads are in waiting mode. so i am assuming that only one thread at a time processing data. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @user2768132, if you want to make http requests concurrently, don't use a lock around the requests. I have no idea what you're doing, because there's nothing in your example about http requests, databases, etc.

Comment: Sorry for that if i am not able to make you understand about my requirement. forget about the example which i have shared. actually my requirement is to process 1000000 data with multiple gorouting. for example, i have 1000000 customer id. i am running a for loop till 1000000. in the for loop i am hitting the HTTP request to get the customer details and i am writing all the customer details in to the file. so that next level can process.and all this i wanted with multi-threading. i am not able to achieve my requirement by above example. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Please let me know if you needed any other details.

Comment: @user2768132: comments are not the place to ask new questions. Please ask a new question with a reproducible example of the problem you're having.